# call function in a class from another PHP file

Tags: php, function, class, oop, instance

i want to call a function in a class from another php file, i must create instance later?

```
login.php
<?php
class Login
{
   public function validate()
   {

   }
}
?>

index.php
<?php
include 'login.php'
$login = new Login();
$login -> validate();
?>
```

or i create instance in login class first?

```
login.php
<?php
class Login
{
   public function validate()
   {

   }
}

$login = new Login();
?>

index.php
<?php
include 'login.php'
$login -> validate();
?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create an instance to call a function belonging to a class. You can utilize [static methods](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_static_methods.asp) (functions), which are not specific to an instance.

I would also suggest you make use of [autoload feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which will include needed classes automatically for you.

For example if you would like Login class to do some validation for you:

```
<?php

class Login {

    public static function validate($username, $password) {
        //check values against validation rules here 
    }

}
```

to use it you would go:

```
Login::validate('john.doe', 'strongPassword12');
```